# Electron/Node.js treeview with more than one column

Tags: node.js, treeview, electron

I'm looking for a way to build a multi column listview or treeview that works similar to the OSX file explorer, except for data instead of files/folders.

I need to:

- have column headers (similar to the "Name", "Date Modified", etc below)
- the first column to be expandable/collapsible (as the folders are)
- several additional columns for data fields (ideally the user could pick which are shown and/or change the order)

[image: finder]

I saw that Electron has [dialogs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog), but as far as I can tell, these are meant specifically for file/folders, and not general enough for a data display use case. I also found a few treeview libraries such as [js-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-treeview), but as far as I can tell, this is similar to only having the first column ("Name") in the case of OSX, I can only enter text fields and only have one column.

Does there exist a package that is flexible to have the similar functionality to the OSX finder window, but can be applied to a dataset without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I searched around for a robust "treeview" JS component and did not find any which were supported or had a very rich feature set.

I've ended up using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) with some customization. It's a great component and is well supported by the developer. It is more of a "listview" than a "treeview" component – though it does allow grouping and nesting of data, dragging between groups (folders) and lots of customization.

Answer (score 0):

A tree view function for Tabulator will be coming in the next six months :)